# Why strcat() causes causes segmentation fault in the fallowing code?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcat

Why the below code results in segmentation fault?

```
#include<studio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{
    char *name="Kaveri";
    char *rd="Rajshekhar";
    strcat(name,rd);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: You attempt to write to memory occupied by a string literal; and having a buffer overrun to boot. This program exhibits undefined behavior. The first parameter of `strcat` is expected to point to a writable buffer large enough to hold the concatenation of two strings; your buffer is neither writable nor large enough.

Answer (score 3):

For [`strcat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) to work, the destination buffer must be writable and long enough to hold the concatenated output with null termination. From the man page:

> *The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;*

In your case, the destination is a pointer to the first element of a string literal, attempt to modify which invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Segmentation fault is one of the many side effects of undefined behaviour.

To solve this, either

- make the `name` an array, with a big-enough dimension, like

  ```
    char name[128] = "Kaveri";
  ```
- use allocator function to allocate enough memory to `name`, like

  ```
    char *name = malloc(128);  //sizeof(char) == 1
    strcpy(name, "Kaveri");
  ```

and then use `name` as the destination buffer for `strcat`.